# Enable and Disable UITableview scroll based on UITableview cell movement on dragging

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am creating one application based on [FMMoveTableView](https://github.com/FlorianMielke/FMMoveTableView) where I have to drag cell on long press and change its position with in same section and different section.The cell is dragging fine and setting in the same and different section.But the problem is when I start dragging the cell upwards the table also starts scrolling up.So some of its cells are invisible because of bounce where we want to keep the dragged cell.The same thing is happening when I drag the cell to the bottom.

Is it anything related to UITableView property or I have to do it programmatically?

The app FMMoveTableView which I followed for this functionality,it is working fine where it is using UITableView class type.I implemented it in UIViewController class where I made some other views.

**UITableView Properties:**

```
 self.GroupedTableView=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 25, 280, 480) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    self.GroupedTableView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator=YES;
    self.GroupedTableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=YES;
    self.GroupedTableView.bounces=YES;
    self.GroupedTableView.alwaysBounceHorizontal=NO;
    self.GroupedTableView.alwaysBounceVertical=YES;
    self.GroupedTableView.bouncesZoom=YES;
    self.GroupedTableView.delaysContentTouches=YES;
    self.GroupedTableView.canCancelContentTouches=YES;
    self.GroupedTableView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    self.GroupedTableView.dataSource=self;
    self.GroupedTableView.delegate=self;
    self.GroupedTableView.rowHeight=30;
    self.GroupedTableView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    self.GroupedTableView.tag=202;
    [self.view addSubview:self.GroupedTableView];
```

**Long Press Gesture:**

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *movingGestureRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
    [movingGestureRecognizer setDelegate:self];
    [self.GroupedTableView addGestureRecognizer:movingGestureRecognizer];
```

**Auto Scroll Methods:**

```
- (void)legalizeAutoscrollDistance
{
    float minimumLegalDistance = [self.GroupedTableView contentOffset].y * -1;

    float maximumLegalDistance = [self.GroupedTableView contentSize].height - ([self.GroupedTableView frame].size.height + [self.GroupedTableView contentOffset].y);

    [self setAutoscrollDistance:MAX([self autoscrollDistance], minimumLegalDistance)];
    [self setAutoscrollDistance:MIN([self autoscrollDistance], maximumLegalDistance)];
}

- (void)stopAutoscrolling
{
    [self setAutoscrollDistance:0];
    [[self autoscrollTimer] invalidate];
    [self setAutoscrollTimer:nil];
}


- (void)maybeAutoscrollForSnapShotImageView:(FMSnapShotImageView *)snapShot
{
    [self setAutoscrollDistance:0];

    NSLog(@"Height====%f",[self.GroupedTableView frame].size.height);
    NSLog(@"Height====%f",[self.GroupedTableView contentSize].height);
    NSLog(@"Frame====%@",NSStringFromCGRect([snapShot frame]));
    NSLog(@"Frame====%@",NSStringFromCGRect([self.GroupedTableView bounds]));

    // Check for autoscrolling
    // 1. The content size is bigger than the frame's
    // 2. The snap shot is still inside the table view's bounds

    if ([self.GroupedTableView frame].size.height < [self.GroupedTableView contentSize].height && CGRectIntersectsRect([snapShot frame], [self.GroupedTableView bounds]))
    {
        CGPoint touchLocation = [[self movingGestureRecognizer] locationInView:self.GroupedTableView];
        touchLocation.y += [self touchOffset].y;

        float distanceToTopEdge  = touchLocation.y - CGRectGetMinY([self.GroupedTableView bounds]);
        float distanceToBottomEdge = CGRectGetMaxY([self.GroupedTableView bounds]) - touchLocation.y;

        if (distanceToTopEdge < [self autoscrollThreshold])
        {
            [self setAutoscrollDistance:[self autoscrollDistanceForProximityToEdge:distanceToTopEdge] * -1];
        }
        else if (distanceToBottomEdge < [self autoscrollThreshold])
        {
            [self setAutoscrollDistance:[self autoscrollDistanceForProximityToEdge:distanceToBottomEdge]];
        }
    }

    if ([self autoscrollDistance] == 0)
    {
        [[self autoscrollTimer] invalidate];
        [self setAutoscrollTimer:nil];
    }
    else if (![self autoscrollTimer])
    {
        NSTimer *autoscrollTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0 / 60.0) target:self selector:@selector(autoscrollTimerFired:) userInfo:snapShot repeats:YES];
        [self setAutoscrollTimer:autoscrollTimer];
    }
}

- (void)autoscrollTimerFired:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    [self legalizeAutoscrollDistance];

    CGPoint contentOffset = [self.GroupedTableView contentOffset];
    contentOffset.y += [self autoscrollDistance];
    [self.GroupedTableView setContentOffset:contentOffset];

    // Move the snap shot appropriately
    FMSnapShotImageView *snapShot = (FMSnapShotImageView *)[timer userInfo];
    [snapShot moveByOffset:CGPointMake(0, [self autoscrollDistance])];

    // Even if we autoscroll we need to update the moved cell's index path
    CGPoint touchLocation = [[self movingGestureRecognizer] locationInView:self.GroupedTableView];
    [self moveRowToLocation:touchLocation];
}



- (float)autoscrollDistanceForProximityToEdge:(float)proximity
{
    return ceilf(([self autoscrollThreshold] - proximity) / 5.0);
}
```

**I am unable to stop tableview scroll when I drag a cell.What I need that table should not move till the dragged cell has not reached to the top or bottom and then it should scroll to show hidden Cells.**

Comment: Is there a reason that you arent using native UITableView move cell?

Comment: looks like a lot of programing for smth that table view can do on its own

Comment: For the default functionality we can do only by clicking extreme left of the row.But in my case I have to move the cell where ever I long press in the cell as what I know.Is there anything else then please suggest?

Comment: I have created a dummy app with just a UITableView in my main UIViewController and I programatically added UILongGestureReogniser to it, just like U did, and my app is behaving just as U would like it to, when long gesture is recognized the table doesnt scroll, so it must be some kind of implementation problem. Does it happen always or just sometimes?

Comment: It happens always when I go either at the top or at the bottom.

Comment: Can you give me the sample you made?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41169/discussion-between-antonijodev-and-imran)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the **solution**.Actually I am using some gestures on my table view cell.So to enable this along with other gestures I was using:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
     return YES;

}
```

So this was actually activating the UITableView gestures too when it was not needed.And so When I dragged the cell Image my table also started scrolling along with the image.I misinterpreted it as my implementation for row sliding has got some issue.So code used in question works is fine if someone needs it in future.What I did is added some conditions in the above method and activated it when it was needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
// //  ViewController.h //  testingApp
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *reco; }

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITableView *table;

@end



//
//  ViewController.m
//  testingApp

#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize table;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    reco = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(recognize:)];
    [self.table addGestureRecognizer:reco];
}


-(void)recognize:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"recognize");
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 5;
}

// Row display. Implementers should *always* try to reuse cells by setting each cell's reuseIdentifier and querying for available reusable cells with dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
// Cell gets various attributes set automatically based on table (separators) and data source (accessory views, editing controls)

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

    return cell;
}

@end
```

Comment: yeah but I have to show one cell that is picked moving around the whole tableview.